# React router componentwillleave not calling

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, react-router, gsap

Im trying to animate react router pages with `TransitionGroup` and `gsap`
App

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              //links
            </ul>
              <div className="detail">
                <TransitionGroup component="div">
                  {this.props.children}
                </TransitionGroup>
              </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Page component, only `componentDidMount` action is calling and animating, `componentWillLeave` not working.

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // working
        var dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
        TweenMax.fromTo(dom, 0.3, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1})
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            Page
          </div>
        )
    }
    componentWillLeave() {
        // not working
        var dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
        TweenMax.fromTo(dom, 0.3, {y: 0, opacity: 1}, {y: 100, opacity:0})
    }
}
```

Im new to react, i have complex animations with each page loading and leaving, please help me to find a solution to fix this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `componentWillUnmount` is not the lifecycle method you're looking for?

Comment: I'v tried `componentWillUnmount ` it's triggering but not supports animations.

Comment: I believe that you're supposed to call the fade out animations from that method. Do you mind changing the original question to use `componentWillUnmount`? That will make it a bit easier to reason

Comment: `componentWillUnmount ` not working with animations.

Comment: One way or the other, `componentWillLeave` is not a lifecycle method thus it is not being called as per specs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know what I was talking about. I believe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36845704/3964612
You will need to change your `componentDidMount` to `componentWillEnter` and call the callback function both there and in `componentWillLeave`